# Is leapmotion a scam?

Tags: consumer-products, computers

Looking for altertative ways of Human–computer interaction, I found [www.leapmotion.com](http://www.leapmotion.com), which looks promising.  They say in the website and in some interviews that they will release this device to the market in winter 2012, and they have a pre-order page on the web site.

Has anyone found any evidence that this is not a scam?

Comment: [Wired](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/05/why-the-leap-is-the-best-gesture-control-system-weve-ever-tested/) has tested it.

Comment: btw. in the Fruit Ninja example you can see that it doesn't have pressed / not pressed equivalent. Seems like using a mouse with the button stuck in down position...

Comment: If anything it might be too good. When Slashdot covered it, someone commented that they didn't think it could be real because if it was, it would revolutionize some aspect of Computer Aided Manufacturing and send some companies out of business. 

My own worry isn't so much that it's a scam but rather it will work really well, get bought up by some PC manufacturer and then become a niche thing you can only get by buying their machines.

Comment: @MarkAllen "If anything it might be too good" That is actually what motivated me for asking this question, it looks to good to be true

Comment: @yms Yep. I first saw it on /. followed by Engadget, but the Engadget piece was pretty much just the press release, so I wrote the reporter and asked him for more. They did a follow up but it was only the Leap people themselves using the device. I hadn't seen the Wired article until I came here, and there's about a two-Mississippi time period of the Wired guy actually using the thing. I remain torn. I want to believe in it, I really do, and the Wired article is pretty convincing. I'm still scared it'll get bought up and preorders cancelled. Time will tell.

Comment: There's nothing that is so *wildly* advanced to be unbelievable. I think what makes the video impressive is the impression of incredibly high precision and tracking, but that lies in the realm of incrementalism. Major question would be whether the precision is based on precise positioning of the fingertips in space (i.e., in a single 2D plane directly above the device) or whether the s/w induces the "fingertip" location in actual 3D space (very hard to do).

Comment: Not a scam, just a pain in the ass. It won't be as bad as a vertical touchscreen, but it will have the same annoying effect on your arms: they will tire quickly if you use LeapMotion regularly.

Comment: Just in case someone wants to know, I ended up making a pre-order of this thing. I will leave a comment here if I ever actually receive it.

Comment: I feel tricked to say the least!
LEAP motion has duped hundred thousands if not a million of people who believed that they would, by providing their banking information for a pre-order for their motion sensor for one reason only.
That is NOT to fulfill their promise to deliver, but to get secure orders to attract investors.
I have ordered 2 devices and not received as much as a confirmation of my order, neither have I received any response to my e-mails. Has ANYONE received order-confirmation or even the promised device??? All those, who have provided their billing-info in good faith should as

Comment: @ProfMOZ: yes, the OP has, there is a photo in the question.

Comment: Maybe you should post the picture of the unit as an answer as opposed to an update to the question?

Comment: @RobZ Good idea. Done!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The word "scam" suggests fraudulence - a deliberate intention to deceive. It is a strong accusation, and we should be careful about wielding it without evidence.

Given [Leap Motion](https://live.leapmotion.com/order.html) claim that they will not charge until the product is shipped *and* that they bill via credit-card, which enables consumers and the banks to recover their money if they charge without delivering, this is not a scam.

That still leaves other options.

It may be [vaporware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaporware) and never get delivered. The fact they had a unit to deliver to [Wired](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/05/why-the-leap-is-the-best-gesture-control-system-weve-ever-tested/) [Hat-tip Oliver.] is evidence suggesting this is not the case, but not proof that they can get the item into production as planned.

The Wired article warns:

> In person, the pre-production version of the Leap is as impressive as the demo video. Once we have the production model in our hands, we’ll be able to determine if Leap Motion transfers all the magic of its demo unit into the final shipping product.

Another risk is that the actual device may not work as well as the advertising has suggested. It may not be as game-changing as hyped. For example, Wired warns:

> without something concrete to place one’s hands and fingers on, there’s the potential for fatigue after using the system for an entire day

In fact, this is a well-known limitation to human (primate?) physiology that has been understood for decades:

[Jargon File for "Gorilla Arm"](http://catb.org/jargon/html/G/gorilla-arm.html)

> The side-effect that destroyed touch-screens as a mainstream input technology despite a promising start in the early 1980s. It seems the designers of all those spiffy touch-menu systems failed to notice that humans aren't designed to hold their arms in front of their faces making small motions. After more than a very few selections, the arm begins to feel sore, cramped, and oversized — the operator looks like a gorilla while using the touch screen and feels like one afterwards. This is now considered a classic cautionary tale to human-factors designers; “Remember the gorilla arm!” is shorthand for “How is this going to fly in real use?”.

This isn't a quality reference, so I am just using it to illustrate a point - that a "Minority Report"-style user interface may not actually be the ideal UI system for the future.

These caveats are not suggestions that the product is a scam, but that there are normal business risks in dealing with yet-to-be-released products.

Comment: English is not my mother tongue, so sometimes I miss the "strength" or "seriousness" of some words. Thanks for your remarks.

Comment: I had hoped to update this to say "Look they have shipped." but [so far](https://blog.leapmotion.com/labview-hackers-leap-controlled-quadrotor/) they have only shipped out "early access" "developer units".

Comment: Thanks for the update! I just requested a developer unit as well, let's see how that goes for me.

Answer (score 10):

No **leapmotion is not a scam** in the same sense that a ponzi scheme or a perpetual motion machine is a scam. [Wired has tested it](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/05/why-the-leap-is-the-best-gesture-control-system-weve-ever-tested/) and found it to be a useful system.

This does not mean that leapmotion will end up being a world-beating system, or that it will even be released. There are hundreds of things that can come between a working, effective prototype and a best-selling production system that are nothing to do with being a 'scam'. There is no way to evaluate these factors at this stage.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE 2013-Jan-21:**

I just received my developer unit.

[image]

Comment: Can't wait to see leap motion tags in SO :D